# Pulling in data from MySQL and displaying in table using table id in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can someone tell me how `id="datatable"` of table is used to display the content from the `$output`

If unable to answer this, then please tell me : is there is any way to display the whole content dynamically using a variable like `" {CONTENT} ".`

How can i do this ?

Here is my Code :

```
case "user_outgoing_full":
    $base_url = "index.php?app=menu&inc=user_outgoing&op=user_outgoing_full";

    $content = "
        <h2>Outgoing SMS Full Report</h2>
        <table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" class=\"pretty\" id=\"datatable\" style=\"width:100%;table-layout:fixed\">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>To</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Update</th>
            <th style=\"width:7%\">Count</th>
            <th style=\"width:10%\">Status</th>
            <th style=\"width:10%\">Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>    
        <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        </table>";
    if ($err = $_SESSION['error_string']) {
        echo "<div class=error_string>$err</div>";
    }
    echo $content;
    break;
case "user_outgoing_full_data":
        ob_start( 'ob_gzhandler' );
    header( 'Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' );
    header( 'Content-Encoding: gzip' );
    $db_query = "SELECT * FROM "._DB_PREF_."_tblSMSOutgoing"." WHERE uid=".$uid." AND flag_deleted=0 group by p_msg,p_datetime,uid,flag_deleted";
    $db_result = dba_query($db_query);
    while ($db_row = dba_fetch_array($db_result)) {
        $list[] = $db_row;
    }
    $j=0;
    $maxcount = count($list);
    $output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $maxcount,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $maxcount,
    "aaData" => array()
    );
    for ($j=0;$j<$maxcount;$j++) {
        $row = array();
        $list[$j] = core_display_data($list[$j]);
        $smslog_id = $list[$j]['smslog_id'];
        $c_count=$list[$j]['count'];
        $p_dst = $list[$j]['p_dst'];
        $p_desc = phonebook_number2name($p_dst);
        $current_p_dst = $p_dst;
        if ($p_desc) {
            $current_p_dst = "$p_dst<br />$p_desc";
        }
        $p_sms_type = $list[$j]['p_sms_type'];
        if (($p_footer = $list[$j]['p_footer']) && (($p_sms_type == "text") || ($p_sms_type == "flash"))) {
            $p_msg = $p_msg.' '.$p_footer;
        }
        $p_datetime = core_display_datetime($list[$j]['p_datetime']);
        $p_update = core_display_datetime($list[$j]['p_update']);
        $p_status = $list[$j]['p_status'];
        $p_gpid = $list[$j]['p_gpid'];
        // 0 = pending
        // 1 = sent
        // 2 = failed
        // 3 = delivered
        // 4 = DND
        /*if ($p_status == "1") {
            $p_status = "<span class=status_sent />";
        } else if ($p_status == "2") {
            $p_status = "<span class=status_failed />";
        } else if ($p_status == "3") {
            $p_status = "<span class=status_delivered />";
        } else {
            $p_status = "<span class=status_pending />";
        }
        $p_status = strtolower($p_status);*/
        if ($p_status == "1") {
            $p_status = "SENT";
        } else if ($p_status == "2") {
            $p_status = "FAILED";
        } else if ($p_status == "3") {
            $p_status = "DELIVERED";
        } else if ($p_status == "4") {
            $p_status = "DND";
        } else {
            $p_status = "PENDING";
        }
        if ($p_gpid) {
            $p_gpcode = strtoupper(phonebook_groupid2code($p_gpid));
        } else {
            $p_gpcode = "&nbsp;";
        }
        $msg = $list[$j]['p_msg'];
        $p_msg = core_display_text($msg);
        if ($msg && $p_dst) {
            $resend = _a('index.php?app=menu&inc=send_sms&op=sendsmstopv&do=reply&message='.urlencode($msg).'&to='.urlencode($p_dst), $core_config['icon']['resend']);
            $forward = _a('index.php?app=menu&inc=send_sms&op=sendsmstopv&do=forward&message='.urlencode($msg), $core_config['icon']['forward']);
        }
        $c_option = $resend."&nbsp".$forward;

        $row[] = $p_datetime;
        $row[] = $current_p_dst;
        $row[] = $p_msg;
        $row[] = $p_update;
        $row[] = $c_count;
        $row[] = $p_status;
        $row[]=  $c_option;
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode( $output );
    exit();
    break;
```

Comment: There exists some javascript loading the data from the second case statement via AJAX und putting it into the table which is outputted in the upper part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript

This code is with [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/), javascript library

```
function newTable(value1,value2){

    $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url:"../yourDirectory/your.php",
       data: {var1: value1,
              var2: value2
       },
       success:function(data){
               $("#datatable").html( data ) ;
       } 
   });
}
```

the code inside data :{ }  are the variables for php , in your code $_REQUEST["var1"]
 or  $_REQUEST["var2"].
For new table from php you have to call function newTable()